# Solving Laplace equation in a square with one insulated border

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, eigenfunctions

I keep getting stuck on this problem, so if someone could point out where my method is flawed and how I should approach this problem, that would be extremely useful.

We're considering the square region $0\leq x \leq \pi, 0\leq y \leq \pi$ with the boundary conditions $u(\pi,y)=u(0,0)=0, u(x,\pi)=f(x)=\cos(\dfrac{3}{2}x)$, and the left border ($u(0,y$) is "insulated", which I interpret to mean $\partial_xu=0$.

I start off with the condition $u(x,y)=X(x)Y(y)\rightarrow\dfrac{X''}{X}+\dfrac{Y''}{Y}=0$ and I equate the X fraction with $+\lambda$ and the Y fraction with $-\lambda$.  The error I run into is when I solve for X: I get $X''-\lambda X=0$ and $\lambda=n^2\rightarrow  X(x)=c_1e^{nx}+c_2e^{-nx}, X(\pi)=0\rightarrow c_2=-c_1e^{2\pi n}$.  $X(x)=c_1(e^{nx}-e^{n(2\pi-x)}\rightarrow X'(x)=c_1(ne^{xn}+ne^{n(2\pi-x)})=0\rightarrow c_1=0$.

So now I get the trivial solution... my professor mentioned that we get the trivial solution because the assumption $u(x,y)=X(x)Y(y)$, but he never told us what to do instead and he doesn't give any details in the lecture notes, so I'm pretty lost.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You have demonstrated that $\lambda>0$ won't work. It has to be negative, and so $X$ will be a combination of trigonometric functions, not exponentials. This should be expected in general: the functions that satisfy the homogeneous boundary conditions can't be exponential.

Comment: ^ if you could give insight towards how to solve the problem instead of giving me the correct answer via your inspection, that would be very helpful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From
$$
\frac{X''}{X}+\frac{Y''}{Y}=\lambda
$$
and the boundary conditions we get for $X$
$$
X''-\lambda\,X=0,\quad X'(0)=0,\quad X(\pi)=0.
$$
This has the nontrivial solution
$$
X(x)=\cos\Bigl(\frac{2\,k+1}{2}\,x\Bigr),\quad k=0,1,2,\dots
$$
corresponding to
$$
\lambda=-\Bigl(\frac{2\,k+1}{2}\Bigr)^2.
$$
Can you go on from here?